# Problema con claves en EF mvc5 asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo definidas las claves en cada una de esas entidades con el atributo [key] como se puede ver en la foto, a parte de eso esta importado el namespace "using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;" y al crear controladores ocurre esto.

para este caso la clase viajero esta definida asi :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OsAgenciaUSBT.Models
{
    public class Viajero
    {
        [key]
        public int IdViajero { get; set; }
        public string tipoViajero { get; set; }
        public string nombres { get; set; }
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }
        public int telefono { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Update { get { return DateTime.Now; } }


        public virtual ICollection<Venta> Venta { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: que mas puedo poner al respecto?

Answer (score 1):

Noto que el atributo que usas es `key` con una `k` minúscula. Eso no está bien. El atributo que debes usar es `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute`, o simplemente `Key` (con mayúscula).

Es posible que accidentalmente creaste una clase `keyAttribute` en alguna parte en tu proyecto, y ahora estás usando ese atributo de forma errónea. Busca por donde anda esta clase confusa y elimínala para evitar más problemas. (De hecho, en tu captura de pantalla puedo ver la clase `keyAttribute.cs` en tu segundo tab. ¡Elimínalo!)